# Boot device not found 3f0

Tags: hard-drive

I started my hp6460 this morning and it's telling me to install an OS on my hard disk. I'm running Windows 10 and all disk self tests have failed and say disk not found

Comment: Time to buy a new drive, by the sounds of it.

Comment: Thanks buddy any suggestions on where and what type I should buy?

Comment: Whatever fits - it's SATA 300 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfCNOu5QeSE

Answer (score -1):

Try to open the back of your hp6460 if you can. then re connect it. if its still not working or if you hear some ticking sound inside then its dead. if doesnt hear anything try to slave it first to other unit if you have if still not working then thats it. you need to purchase a different one or if under warranty you can claim it.